# What's the difference between "adviser" and "advisor" -- are both interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, orthography, suffixes, agent-noun-suffix

I work for a financial services provider and we deal with "Financial Advisors" all the time. Increasingly, I'm seeing people send emails and so forth with the term "Financial Adviser" and the terms *adivsor* and *adviser* seem to be increasingly interchangeable.

Which then raises the question: what is the difference between *adviser* and *advisor*?

Comment: Related: [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/)

Comment: There's a full discussion of the _-or / -er_ issue on Language Log: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=22378

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both are right. This is how the [Oxford dictionary entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adviser) explains the usage:

> The spellings adviser and advisor are
>   both correct. Adviser is more common,
>   but advisor is also widely used,
>   especially in North America. Adviser
>   may be seen as less formal, while
>   advisor often suggests an official
>   position

Comment: [Related post](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/10/agentive-suffixes-er-and-or-and-little.html) on the *Separated by a common language* blog: "[T]he -or form is stronger in the US than the UK, though there's considerable variation within each country." And: "[I]n my job, I advise students and convene courses, and when I spell out those roles, I'm an **advisor** and a **convenor**, but when my UK university spells them, I'm often an **adviser** (which just looks wrong to me) and a **convener**. (Incidentally, Blogger's allegedly AmE spellchecker likes the -er forms.)"

Answer (score 7):

I just happened to come across this issue writing a final exam for a course in international financial derivatives regulation.  (For those of you who don't know what that is, it's what you do in purgatory.)  ***Both spellings are correct.***  In general,"adviser" is the preferred spelling, especially in the UK.  "Advisor" carries a connotation of someone whose professional capacity is to give advice.  On that basis, and since my course had a strong focus on American regulation, I changed "adviser" to "advisor" regarding "very-high-net-worth individuals ... who tend to employ the service of sophisticated advisors to assess and manage their risk." If you want to know my sources, just google "adviser or advisor" like I did and you'll get them all.

Can't resist taking a swipe at the obiter on "amount" vs. "number" in the media.  My two fields are English Literature and Law.  Like Law, English grammar is based on rules which must be faithfully applied in order to preserve a unified fabric, but like Law, English is (forsooth) a living language. It lives and is preserved our media of communication.  When the editors of the OED want to know what the "correct" usage of a certain term was in the 19th century, they turn to ... the media!  I'm the first to be a stickler for good usage, but don't overdo it.

Answer (score 4):

I got my hands dirty by digging through data about how our tech society handles one word with two spellings:

[**Advisor or Adviser: A data-journey for one word that goes both ways**](https://smalldata.dev/posts/advisor-or-adviser/)

**tl;dr** the spellings are interchangeable. Some publishers have style guides that require one spelling or the other. By counting usage, some leading words show more prevalence of O or E, e.g. jewelry adviser is much more used than jewelry advisor, and stock advisor is much more commonly used instead of stock adviser.

Here is a chart showing ratio of O:E spellings for many leading words:

[image]

---

In it you'll find polarized opinions, such as:

[image]

And also people who couldn't care less:

[image]

Comment: I'd shy away from that last fellow just for his carelessness.  Seems like the kind who would leave the sugar out of lemonade.

Answer (score 3):

Advisor should be the preferred spelling, consistent with other official titles:

actor
convenor
coordinator
editor
regulator

I am a professional general and scientific editor with over 40-years experience.

The tragedy is that the media often perpetuates mis-spellings and mis-use, witness the current use of 'amount' for every quantitative description, e.g. *amount* [sic] of people, rather than *number* of people.

Comment: Your answer appears to be merely a personal opinion, and is contradicted by the authoritative references quoted in the other two answers, one of which specifically makes a distinction between US & UK usage. Which are you speaking about? Also, please confine your answers to the relevant question. I happen to agree with your comments about "amount", but it's off-topic for this question.

Comment: @TrevorD It's a personal opinion, but she states the reasoning behind her preference: consistency with other English spellings. Given that both spellings are correct, and that "adviser" may look wrong to many people, this is a valid consideration.

Comment: What about "teacher," "lecturer," "writer," "producer"?

Comment: Agent nouns in English are *almost* always formed with -er rather than -or.  You need to explain rather more clearly why "adviser"/"advisor" should be the exception (particularly in the light of the fact that "adviser" is actually the most common spelling).

Comment: Marion is an editor, not an "editer". By the same measure, the "teacher," "lecturer," "writer," "producer" post appears to be mere whataboutery (an amusing term, which I am relieved to find is now in the dictionary). I'm also a UK native speaker translator, reviewer and post editor and I too prefer the "advisor" spelling.

Comment: Marion, you say "Advisor should be the preferred spelling, consistent with other official titles". What is your reference for this? The OED says both are correct. Are you merely expressing a preference?

Answer (score 3):

In Australian Financial Services, the legislation uses the spelling *Advis**e**r* so that is the source of truth in Industry. In regular Australian vernacular both spellings are used.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest reference book to my computer, the ["Oxford Writers' Dictionary"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192826697), says

> **advis/er** *not* -or; **ory**

Answer (score 2):

I am an academic advisor. I have seen the term used both way, and after thinking about it, I think that the distinction between one who is a professional advisor and once who gives advice on an informal basis should be maintained. I had previously called myself an "adviser." Now I am an "advisor."

I should point out, however, that there is no difference in pronunciation. I would not want to assert some distinction that does not exist, as in those ridiculous advertisements that over-articulate the last syllable in "realtor." Regardless of spelling, the ultimate vowel is still a schwa.

Answer (score 1):

While in general *adviser* and *advisor* mean the same thing, it appears in at least one context that is not true.

In Canadian banks [financial advisers are subject to regulation, but financial advisors are not](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/bank-s-deceptive-titles-put-investments-at-risk-1.4044702).