# What’s the rule for adding “-er” vs. “-or” when forming an agent noun from a verb?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, morphology, derivational-morphology, agent-noun-suffix

What’s the rule to decide whether you add *-er* or whether you add *-or* when creating an agent noun from a verb?

Sometimes it’s *-er*:

- *read > reader*
- *hate > hater*
- *hit > hitter*

But other times it’s *-or*:

- *meditate > meditator*
- *collect > collector*

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This has been previously touched on here: [“Commentor” vs “Commentator”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/commentor-vs-commentator). I'll try to expand on that.

Both *-er* and *-or* are so-called "agent noun suffixes", and Wiktionary has entries for both:

- [-er](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er#Etymology_1)
- [-or](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-or#Suffix)

Generally speaking, *-er* is much more common in English (which should come as no surprise since it has deep Germanic roots, see the link) and can be easily attached to any English verb to form the corresponding noun (*drive* — *driver*, *run* — *runner*, *drink* — *drinker*, etc.).

The suffix *-or*, on the other hand, comes from Latin, and is used much more seldom, basically where Latin would do it. Just try building the words *drivor*, *runnor* or *drinkor*, and see for yourself. In fact, Wiktionary lists only a handful of terms that were derived using this suffix, such as *actor*, *author* and *sculptor*, and goes on to provide the following usage notes:

> English generally appends this suffix where Latin would do it—to the root of a Latin-type perfect passive participle. For other words, English tends to use the suffix *-er*. Occasionally both are used (*computer* vs. *computor*).

Etymonline has additional info on the origin and usage of [*-er*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=-er&searchmode=none) and [*-or*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=-or&searchmode=none).

**Edit:** courtesy of Martha, here's a link to [a post on the "Separated by a common language" blog](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/10/agentive-suffixes-er-and-or-and-little.html) that provides further details and addresses the differences between US and UK English:

> The *-or* suffix is primarily found in words derived from Latin, whereas *-er* can be put on the end of just about any verb that involves an agent (a 'doer' of the 'action'). But Latin-derived words differ in how strongly they are associated with the *-or* suffix. Latin-derived verbs that end in *-ate*, for example, almost always take the *-or* suffix. So we have *dictator*, but not a variant *dictater*, *alternator* but not *alternater*.
>
> Things are less clear-cut with other Latin-derived verbs. For example, in my job, I advise students and convene courses, and when I spell out those roles, I'm an *advisor* and a *convenor*, but when my UK university spells them, I'm often an *adviser* (which just looks wrong to me) and a *convener*.
>   [...] The *-or* form is stronger in the US than the UK, though there's considerable variation within each country.

Comment: There are no 'rules' — that alone enhances the richness of this language.

Comment: They both come from a PIE agentive suffix with two variants ([ablaut grades](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299)): **-ter*, the E-grade, meant a person who had performed some action, while **-tor*, the O-grade, meant a person who generically performs some action (i.e, a professional). It's the difference between simple description (_the murderer_) and occupational generic (_the pitcher for this game_). Of course, that was in PIE. In English it's a tossup which spelling it has, but they're all pronounced the same, so the spelling is irrelevant.

Comment: +0. You write, "... basically where Latin would do it." And where would Latin do it? First conjugation: cantor. Second: splendor but responder. Third: invader. And so on. Or does it have nothing especially to do with the choice of Latin conjugation? Unfortunately, after your answer correctly mentions the Germanic *-er,* it seems substantially incomplete on the Latin—too incomplete to be very helpful. Regarding the sources you quote, they seem neither authoritative nor knowledgeable. I don't think that this is a very good answer; it should not have been *accepted.*

Comment: @JohnLawler: Comments like yours are why I love this site.  I wish I could bookmark/permalink a comment.

Comment: @MarkKCowan You can, click the timestamp.

Comment: @thb I don't even know enough Latin to upvote this comment. But further exploration of the "latin roots" thesis would be interesting.

Comment: Just to add that -ist is another agentive suffix.

Answer (score 15):

The best rule I've found?

If you can change the word to have "ion" at the end, it is OR.  If you can't, it's ER.

TeachER (can not be teachion)
ConductOR (conduction)
ProfessOR (profession)

I can't really think of any ER's sorry!

Comment: It's far from a perfect rule, however; consider *investor*, *proprietor*, *creditor* / *debtor*, *ambassador*, *victor*, *conspirator*, *juror*, and *vendor* among others.

Comment: I agree with choster except for conspirator which can be changed into conspiration

Comment: I actually think this is a good rule of thumb. These words also tend to allow -ive suffixes. It is by no means perfect and there are many exceptions but for common words it works fairly well. act-action-active-actor, emote-(e)motion-(e)motive-motor, instruct-instruction-instructive-instructor. Note "propriet(e)", "ambassad(e)", "vict(e)" and "jur(e)" are not words, let alone verbs although we do have evict-eviction-evictor.

Comment: About 40 years ago I read that for neologisms "er" should be use used for human agency and "or" for mechanisms.  This rule seems to fit much of the computer terminology that has been created since then.

Comment: Note, too, that Merriam-Webster reports that _descrater_ and _corrupter_ are more common in U.S. English than _desecrator_ and _corruptor_, even though the existence of _desecration_ and _corruption_ would point toward the opposite preferences. And _disrupter_ is the only form that MW gives for that noun, despite its ties to the reference noun _disruption_. The guideline you suggest begins to look like a Swiss cheese rule—more substance than air overall, but full of holes.

Comment: @SvenYargs: How six years of "Web3" have changed the landscape! In 2023, Google autocorrects "disrupter" to "disruptor", and [the screenplay for _Glass Onion_](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Glass-Onion-A-Knives-Out-Mystery-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf) spells its group of "disruptors" that way. Moral: An obscure word that "ought" to be spelled a certain way (in AmE), if it becomes popular, _will_ be spelled that way. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disruptor%2Cdisrupter&year_start=1900 (But this might also reflect less disruption by machines and more by people.)

Answer (score 9):

The final consonant of the verb is relevant, indirectly: because of the etymology of the ending *-or*, it is usually found after ***t*** or ***s***. However, there is no simple rule for *-or* vs. *-er* that always gives the right ending, because there are some complications due to both etymology and analogy.

### Latin agent nouns end in *-tor* or *-sor*

As RegDwigнt's answer mentions, verbs that form agent nouns in *-or* usually have the form of Latin perfect passive participle stems.

Latin perfect passive participle stems characteristically end in **t** or **s**. So in practice, verbs that form agent nouns in *-or* almost always  end in *-t(e)* or *-s(e),* and form agent nouns in *-tor* or *-sor* specifically. In the context of Latin, the suffix is often given as *-tor* rather than as *-or.* (There is an unrelated Latin suffix *-or* that forms abstract nouns from verbs, such as *error, rigor, terror*).

Examples:

- *actor* (Latin and English), from the Latin verb *ago* ("do, act"), perfect passive participle stem *act-*

- *possessor* (Latin and English), from the Latin verb *possideo* ("have, hold, possess"), perfect passive participle stem *possess-*

You can see that these two words have the same spelling in modern English as in Latin. For complicated reasons, the corresponding English verbs have the form of the Latin perfect passive particle stems: *act* and *possess.*

### *-or* can follow other consonants in words from French

There are agent nouns in English that end in *-or* preceded by a letter other than *t* or *s*. The main origin of this type of *-or* agent noun is French (specifically, the Anglo-Norman variety that was spoken in England after the Norman conquest). In Old French, the *t* in the Latin ending *-atorem* (as well as some other similar endings) was lost by regular sound change, the *a* turned into a schwa (first spelled *e* and then eventually lost), and as a result the whole thing ended up as *-or/-our/-ur* (Modern French *-eur*). This was taken into Middle English as an agent-noun suffix *-our*. A simplified example: Latin *gubernator* (accusative *gubernatorem*) became Anglo-Norman French *gouvernour*, Middle English *governour,* Modern English *governor.*

In fact, there was extensive spelling variation and some confusion with other suffixes of similar meaning already in French, so the Oxford English Dictionary lists not only *gouvernour* but also *governor, governour, governur, guvernur, governer, guverner* as possible spellings of the Anglo-Norman word, and *couernour, couernoure, gouernowre, gouernur, gounour, gouvernour, guuernere, guuernour, governore, gouernere, governowre, gouerner, gouernor, gouernour, gouernoure, governoure, governour, governer* as potential spellings in Middle English.

The ending *-our* was pronounced /uːr/ in Middle English and was at least sometimes stressed (Chaucer rhymes *governour* with *flour* 'flower'¹) but in Modern English, this ending came to be unstressed and its vowel became reduced, making it sound identical in English pronunciation to the *-or* ending found in Latin words. Along with the preexisting variation and the analogical influence of Latin *-or*, this made it easy for the spelling *-our* to be simplified in most cases to *-or.*

- A large proportion of *-or* agent nouns only occur in legal English, where *-or* is used more than in regular English (often as a counterpart to *-ee*). For example, "deliveror" and "settlor" are basically only found in legal contexts; in other contexts, the spellings "deliverer" and "settler" are used.
- Some *-or* agent nouns that are not restricted to legal English are *conquer-or, purvey-or, survey-or, counsel-(l)-or,* and *vend-or* (the last has a less common but accepted variant *vend-er*). These all originate from (Anglo-Norman) French nouns, but can be reinterpreted in modern English as suffixed derivatives of the English verbs *conquer, purvey, survey, counsel, vend.*
- *sail-or* is an example of the French suffix being used on an English base, the verb *sail.*

There are other *-or* words that don't end in *-tor* or *-sor,* but most of the rest cannot be interpreted as being built directly on an English verb as a base. For example, *donor, emperor, tailor, juror* don't refer to people who "done", "emper", "tail" or "jure".

There seems to be sporadic use in English of the spelling *-or* instead of *-er* simply as a way of forming words with a specialized meaning, sometimes as part of technical terminology or jargon.

- The Oxford English Dictionary entry for the word "sailor" describes it as "An altered spelling of sailer n., probably assimilated to tailor, in order to distinguish the designation of a regular calling from the unspecialized agent-noun. The differentiation, however, does not appear in our early examples, and was not fully established before the 19th cent."
- In electronics, the form "[expandor](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/expandor)", as well as a derived term "compandor" (from *compressor* and *expandor*), has apparently been used.

### It's hard to rule out the spelling *-er*

Ending in *-t*, *-te,* *-s* or *-se* is mostly necessary for a verb to form an agent noun in *-or* (with exceptions, as discussed above), but it certainly isn't sufficient.

- [Sven Yargs left a comment mentioning "disrupter"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-forming-an-agent-noun-from-a-ver/486896#comment803421_137523) as an example of an agent noun that is commonly spelled with *-ter* (although the spelling *disruptor* also exists). *Adopter, corrupter, tempter, respecter* are other difficult-to-predict common spellings in *-ter.*
- *User* and *passer* are always spelled with *-ser.*

The suffix *-er* is highly productive and is used to form nouns with a range of meanings. I don't think any rule based on meaning will be reliable as a guide to using *-er* vs. *-or.* To give counterexamples to some alleged rules that I've sometimes seen:

- Words ending in *-er* can be animate (*runner, worker, speaker, reader*) or inanimate (*washer, dryer, circuit breaker, holder*). Words ending in *-or* also can be animate (*administrator, director*) or inanimate (*elevator, insulator, ventilator*).
- Words ending in *-er* can be names of professions (*teacher, writer, baker, publisher, typographer, undertaker*), as can words ending in *-or* (*sculptor, legislator, conductor*).

---

¹"Appollo, god and governour / Of every plaunte, herbe, tree and flour"—"The Franklin's Tale"