# One who creates is a creator. What is one who updates?

Tags: single-word-requests, agent-noun-suffix

One who creates is a creator. What is one who updates?

- An updater?
- An updator?

The last one seems more logical, but also wrong.

Comment: A _natural selector_.

Comment: @arex1337 Don't accept answers too quickly! You've gotten a nice answer, but I'm sure there might be a few people out there who have a little something to add, perhaps even one who can top the current highest-ranked answer. You see, if you accept too quickly, the software gives your question less visibility and it ultimately withers on the vine; not every question can be answered immediately.  I'd advise waiting a day or two at least.

Comment: Related: [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/)

Comment: Why does the second one seem more logical?

Comment: While you're worrying about which spelling to use on theoretical grounds, you might like to bear in mind that usage has already established the -er spelling fairly convincingly. Google "software updater" and you get 1.7 million results compared to 29 thousand for "software updator".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [Dr. Goodword's Language Blog](http://www.alphadictionary.com/blog/?p=260),

> Generally, -or is a Latin suffix and -er is the Germanic equivalent meaning, roughly, “one who Vs”, where V represents any verb. Words borrowed directly from Latin, then, tend to end with -or: governor, calculator, arbitrator, legislator, alternator. Words of Germanic origin (English is a Germanic language) generally take -er: runner, thinker, worker, joker.
>
> However, two factors muddy the water.  English borrowed many words from French in the Middle Ages and the French equivalent of -or and -er, is -eur.  English generally reduced that suffix to -er, keeping it only in a few words borrowed late: amateur, restaurateur, raconteur [...]
>
> [...] you need to know the etymologies of many of the verbs that -er and -or are added to, in order to know how to distribute them. You can be sure that verbs ending with -ize and -ify will take the suffix -er and that verbs ending on the suffix -ate will be suffixed with -or.

You may note that "update" ends with "-ate"; however, it is not a *suffix*, as it is in words like *asphyxiate* and *elongate*.  According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/date), "update" is "up-" + "date", and "date" came to English via French, and therefore according to the information above should take "-er" as its suffix.  (Indeed, dictionary.com lists "updater" in its set of related forms.)

Comment: Good answer. BUT we don't need to be too philosophical about this: in practice, "(software) updater" with -er is reasonably well established.

Comment: Anyone who thinks a restaurant owner is a *restauranteur* weakens his authority on etymology.

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Comment: A few words are used with both endings, as variants of each other.

Comment: ok "or" is a latin suffix...so? I don't understand, how does that explain the difference?

Comment: @CharlieParker if the word originates from Latin, it will most likely take the Latin suffix.

Answer (score 7):

I would use **creator** for the person who creates a document/post/record and **editor** for someone who makes subsequent changes.

Comment: I would personally use author instead of creator.

Comment: @ogerard: and how about auther? Oh, sorry, it's way past 1.IV :)

Answer (score 3):

*-er* and *-or* are suffixes used to form nouns denoting a person, animal, or thing that performs a specified action or activity.

In the dictionaries I have, I don't find *updater*, nor *updator*.
If I were to choose, I would choose *updater*.

Comment: I think they call him/her editor.