# What's the difference between "requester" and "requestor"?

Tags: differences, american-english, orthography, agent-noun-suffix

Both are in [dictionaries](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/requestor). I've heard people insist "requester" is correct for a person who requests something, and that "requestor" is wrong there, leaving me to wonder how it is used. *Requestor* happens to be marked as an error in my browser's spellchecker.

[COCA for requester/requestor](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=10713921) indicates that *requester* is used for people and *requestor* is used in technical senses like a part of a program. A [google ngram for requester/requestor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=requester%2Crequestor&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows that *requester* is also a bit more common.

Some [online discussions](http://www.englishforums.com/English/RequesterOrRequestor/jcpz/post.htm) suggest *requestor* may have a meaning in law or be more common there, but I can't find that.

What's the difference in usage? Should *requester* be used for people, or is it more nuanced than that?

Note: These related questions [discuss "creator" and "updater"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/one-who-creates-is-a-creator-what-is-one-who-updates) and [discuss -er and -or endings overall](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb).

Comment: Related: [Advisor vs. adviser](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/), [adaptor vs. adapter](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22537/), [commentor vs. commentator](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/), [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4733/)

Comment: The COCA link is broken.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

With one exception <sup>1</sup> I don't think there is a nuanced difference here but rather multiple formations of the same concept.  As you noted, *requester* is more common than *requestor*.

[This explanation about choosing -er or -or](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723104655/http://www.spellitright.talktalk.net/ends4.html) includes the following:

> 4. -or is used when the base word ends in -ate, -ct, -it :
>    calculate/calculator    create/creator    investigate/investigator
>    contract/contractor    reflect/reflector    conduct/conductor
>    visit/visitor    exhibit/exhibitor    edit/editor

<sup>1</sup> In programming languages that have the concept of an interface you sometimes see the "-or" form, so follow the conventions of whatever domain you're writing in.

Comment: came here for the same reason- database tables are requestor named, and the UI of the application uses the term requester

Comment: The spelling "requestor" should only be used by a programmor. :)

Comment: @GEdgar Exactly! Just like our license to the term "[referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087626/was-the-misspelling-of-the-http-field-name-referer-intentional)".

Comment: Perhaps the "requestor" variant comes from a similarity with "contributor."  But I think @GEdgar has a point.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead and not copy-paste googleable.

Comment: @JosiahYoder thanks for letting me know.  I found it in the Wayback machine and edited that in.  (Eight years later I wonder if there are better sources...)

Comment: Thanks. It is notable that point 4 is the _only_ point that recommends words be ended with _-or_.  I was wondering because "contributor" is _correctly_ spelled only with -_or_ after consulting a few dictionaries.

Comment: The free dictionary lists [224 words ending -ctor](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ctor) and only [121 words ending -cter](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-cter). So that might be a good prefix to add to "part 4".  But -stor does not fair as well: only [99 words end -stor](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-stor) vs. [836 that end in -ster](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ster)

Comment: Programmer interested in good grammar came here for this.  Not sure if feeling validated or ribbed ;)