# Person who invites: "Inviter" or "Invitor"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

There is a clean word that defines person that is invited: *an invitee*.

However, I can't seem to find a straight definition of either terms that would define a person who invites the invitee.

Is it "Inviter", "Invitor"? Is there some other term that is more appropriate?

Comment: Would the _host_ be better suited?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70450/how-to-say-person-who-invites-another-person-with-one-word on ELL

Comment: It's "inviter".  See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/one-who-creates-is-a-creator-what-is-one-who-updates) for some *-er vs. -or* guidelines.

Comment: It is Inviter. as @ThomasFrancois suggested *Host* is the term you would use.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois: I don't think it would. In my view, _host_ implies that there is something being organized somewhere, and the _host_ is _hosting_ that _something_. How about e.g. if a person invites someone to travel with them?

Comment: Would someone please post their suggestion as an answer, so that I can mark the one I prefer? But, of course, there's no rush.

Comment: @MorganFR I didn't know about that sub-site. Thanks.

Comment: ***Invitor*** briefly overtook ***inviter*** in the 50s, but however it's spelt, the "word" has been in [long-term decline for centuries](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invitor%2Cinviter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvitor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinviter%3B%2Cc0). Actual native speakers would almost never use ***invitee*** or ***inviter*** anyway - for example, we'd always ask *Who invited you? Were you invited?*, not *Who was your inviter? Are you an invitee?* On ELL my advice would simply be "Forget about *both* words".

Comment: @FumbleFingers that is the perfect explanation, thank you very much! However, I feel obliged to give a bit more context that you hinted at by saying _native speakers_. I need this in a programming context, where I need to give names to certain things, and I still want to be grammatically correct while doing so.

Comment: @mr.b looks like this is a popular reason. I've found this question because I'm strugling with the same issue as you.

Comment: Even if the usage in everyday language has been declining for decades, it's still useful when designing a database. More succinct than labeling a field "person who invited someone else".

Comment: This question has aged well, given the omnipresent IT demand for the term. Meanwhile, I have side-stepped the whole debate by moving towards a two-word expression, **invited by**, which is easy enough to spell and understand in code and database contexts.

Answer (score 7):

You could use **[Host](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/host_1#host_1__1)** or **Hostess** for its feminine counterpart.

> someone who invites people to a meal or party, or to stay in their home.

However, as pointed out in the comments, it will not be suited in all contexts.

Comment: What if I'm sending invitations to a party that I'm not hosting?