# Is there a single word for a member of a group who completes a job?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, agent-noun-suffix

I have a **job**, for which some people are responsible, say: a, b, c, d and e. If anyone does the job, it is marked as complete.

Now let us say *c* completed the job, so what would I call that person in one word (think **completor** - *not a word*).

It is basically for a database schema for a table of tasks which I have to define. Each task has a list of responsible people. Now as soon as the task is done by someone, it's <strike>completor</strike> field is to be linked to the person who did it.

So what I want is a suitable name for the <strike>completor</strike> field.

Comment: How about sucker?

Comment: How about 'executor'? Seems both appropriate and official sounding.

Comment: In many consulting companies, in professional documentation, the word used for this is **resolver**. Since they solve problems, or resolve issues reported by people.

Comment: There is a [user experience stack exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) that might be helpful with this kind of question. You could argue that the 'user' in this case is the developer who will use your database.

Comment: How about "tasker"? This word is used by some companies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All of the -er words are fine examples, but I can't think of any use of them that won't seem awkward.

Why not use "done by", "completed by", "finished by" or a similar construct?

Comment: I think this is the best answer in context. It is not a single word, but it sounds the best, and I believe would be the most easily understood. (fyi I am also a programmer)

Comment: I like this the best out of all the suggested answers. I can't help thinking that two simple, easy to understand words are a better answer than one convoluted word that feels like its clumsy or stretched when used that way.

Comment: yeah, I also think this would be the best. A db schema no where requires to be a single word.

Comment: +1 I find these constructs not only are clearer, but also align nicely with their time-stamp counterparts: *CreatedOn*, *CompletedOn*, *DeletedOn*, etc. which are normally related.

Answer (score 11):

*Completor* may not be a word, but *completer* is.  Here's the [Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/completer) for it; it can indeed be a noun meaning 'one who completes'.

Comment: I looked at completer but except this page there was no suggestion if it actually means that: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/completer and also I have seen that such type of nouns generally end in *or*, while *er* is more for comparitive sense

Comment: @crodjer; not true re comparative sense - see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er

Comment: @crodjer: [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb)

Answer (score 11):

You might try *finisher*, which suggests "[bringing] a task or activity to an end" [Noad].

Comment: I think this looks the most fitting in my case.

Comment: Please cite source, because dictionary doesn't define "finisher" as a person who finished something.

Comment: @Third Idiot: Yes it does. NOAD: "**finisher** *noun* 1 a person or thing that finishes something ..." NOAD doesn't turn up an entry for *accomplisher*, however, which is your offering.

Comment: Look in the Merriam-Webster

Comment: @Third Idiot: Who made you the arbiter of sources around here?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Third Idiot: You could look it up in the only source you recognize: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arbiter

Comment: Hahaha! I already know what an arbiter is. I was just wondering how I was arbitering the sources.

Comment: @Third: You asked him to cite a source, he cited the New Oxford American Dictionary, and you then told him t check Merriam-Webster (with the implication that MW is more authoritative than NOAD, thus, IMO, the comment re: arbitration).

Comment: @Adam Robinson, Oh, no, that wasn't what I meant. He said that NOAD doesn't turn up an entry for *accomplisher*, so I just cited a source. I wasn't trying to say that NOAD isn't good enough. I use it too, and trust it.

Answer (score 9):

You could go with ***achiever*** (would be my personal choice), *finalizer*, or *fulfiller*.

Comment: I like fulfiller.

Comment: Fulfiller sounds like someone who fulfills the terms of a contract.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

> **Accomplisher**

As in "'c' is an acomplisher"

Comment: Most appropriate term so far, in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

How about [concluder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concluder):

> A person who, or thing which concludes
>   (in any sense)

Answer (score 1):

How about just 'completor'? It's for a database schema, not real life, and it accurately conveys what you want the field to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure you want a "-er" word? In database schemas one typically uses properties, such as "hasFinished", so perhaps this would be a cleaner approach. This assuming that entity in question is member who has finished the job/task; if so, I would find choice of "finisher" (etc) odd; as most commonly "finisher" (etc) would actually point to another entity, and not be a property of that entity.

Comment: He states in the question that this field is intended to point back to the entity that finished the task, so "finisher" (or whatever -er word is chosen) seems appropriate.

Comment: Ah ok. My mistake then, somehow I read it as if this was a boolean property.

Answer (score 1):

Concept:    Agent.
Category:   1. Simple voluntary action
Synonyms:
-nouns
doer, actor, agent, performer, perpetrator, operator; executor, executrix; practitioner, worker

Source: http://thesaurus.com/browse/agent

Many of the words above link to other groups, with similar as well as extended results.

The first word to pop in my head, that related to what you were asking, was "proxy".