# What is the inverse term for a proxy?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm in a similar situation to [crodjer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/27778/1010), in that I am struggling with a word to describe a concept.

In his case, he had a job, for which some people are responsible, say: a, b, c, d and e. In my case, *a* can elect one or more proxies to act on his behalf, say: f and g; similarly, *b* could elect g and h as his proxies.

I'm happy with the term 'proxy' for the person the task has been delegated to, but I wonder what the reverse term is, i.e. in the example above, if *g* is a proxy of *b*, what is *b* to *g*?

Comment: There might be a word specific to your situation - can you give more context as to what is being proxied?

Comment: In a system, several paperwork checks are performed by a set of people - some of the people involved would prefer to delegate their checks to someone else (who may, or may not, report to them)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word you are looking for might be *[principal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/principal)*. Although the more usual pairing is *principal-agent*, I believe that *principal* is correct in such contexts as *proxy voter*, which is nearly what you have in your example.

Comment: +1: I too thought *principal* could be the right candidate, though I could not find any authentic references.

Comment: This is the word I would use in a legal, e.g. company management, situation.

Comment: Slightly more politically correct than Master/Slave which is all I could think of as a pairing...

Comment: Was coming here to ask the same question. Unfortunately in my case I'm designing a DB related to schools and it's a TeacherProxy and TeacherPrincipal but seeing as how there's a set of Principals (ie, actual school admins) in the DB, I think this would be confusing. I'm just going to have to go with TeacherAssignerGuyThing (jk). Thanks! =)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about this, but can we take ***delegator*** as the one who delegates?

Comment: Yes, but this word is purely generic, and for certain things there may be a more idiomatic term, such as principal.

Answer (score 2):

According to *Black's Law Dictionary Online*, "principal" is the correct word for the person who delegates power to an agent or proxy. *Black's*  was first published in Britain; now there are American editions as well. In American law schools, *Black's* is the traditional authority.

Answer (score -1):

There are also **representatives**, **delegates** and **constituents**.