# If someone is my proxy, I am their _____?

Tags: single-word-requests

Bonus question: If I am a proxy for multiple people, what's the collective noun for that group?

Comment: I would say "their principal". But that would probably not be understood unless you had already established that there was a proxy situation happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the inverse term for a proxy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50796/what-is-the-inverse-term-for-a-proxy)

Comment: I think the answer really come down to the capacity in which you are acting as their proxy.   Are you a proxy for certain 'owners' or "constituents' or "shareholders" or "members from this group" or "members from a few groups".  While principal is good,  it still requires elaboration and , to me hearing principals plural , I'd tend to assume that it might be collection of principals with a shared single interest.

Comment: @Tom22 I was going to post an answer saying much the same thing, but I think your comment said it better so I’ll defer to you if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: @nick012000 go ahead and make your answer and flush out whatever extra you were thinking about on top of any similarities to my quick thoughts - I'm off to other hobbies right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Designator** would be one way.

> Attendance passes and **proxy** attendance passes shall be printed in different colors. The pass shall separately record the names of the union member or representative and the **designator**. The **proxies** shall be numbered in serial according to the order of their sign in.
>   During the process of proxy sign-in when it is discovered that a labor union member or representative **designates** more than one **proxy**, all the repeated **designation** shall be deemed as null and void.
>   Article 5
>   If a **designator** attends the meeting in person after the **proxy** has attended the meeting, the **designation** shall be deemed as terminated.

https://laws.mol.gov.tw/Eng/PrintFLAWDAT0202.aspx?lsid=FL059410

Answer (score 6):

It's bit rare, but you would be their ***representee***.

ODO:

> **[representee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/representee)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1** **A person who** or thing which **is represented**. *rare*.

Collins:

> **[representee](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/representee)**
>   *noun*
>
> **3.** *archaic*
>   a person who is represented
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Wiktionary:

> **[representee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/representee)**
>   *Noun*
>
> One who is represented by another.

Comment: Agreed: The proxy is a representative of you. You are their representee.

Answer (score 1):

You are their [**guarantor**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guarantor):

> one that gives a guaranty
>
> In general, a financial guarantee is a promise to take responsibility for another company's financial obligation if that company cannot meet its obligation. The entity assuming this responsibility is the guarantor.

In the case of a proxy, the person presenting the proxy is "backed by" the authority of the people who have given their *guarantee* that the person is speaking on their behalf.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of the situation for which you are acting as a proxy for someone. There are a number of possible answers, but of them seem to have narrow legal or financial connotations- they’re more like field-specific jargon than general English words, so the correct answer would be the one that’s used in the field that you’re dealing with.