# What word refers to a person being acted on behalf of?

Tags: single-word-requests

Using the following definition of **agent**:

> a person who acts on behalf of another person

What word can we use to refer to the person who is being acted on behalf of?

Comment: Closely related [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50796/what-is-the-inverse-term-for-a-proxy/50799).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Oxford Dictionary, the word you are looking for is **Principal**

The definition in Oxford Dictionary is as follows:

> A person for whom another acts as an agent or representative.

[Here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/principal) is the link for the definition in Oxford Dictionary