# Is there a term for a noun that is the "-er" form of a verb?

Tags: nouns

Is there a term for a noun that is the "-er" form of a verb?

For example, one who races is the "racer", and the one who writes is the "writer", so "racer" and "writer" can both be classified as what kind of noun?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The term is [*agent noun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun).

> The endings "-er", "-or", and "-ist" are commonly used in English to form agent nouns.

For further insight, see e.g. this question: [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb)

Comment: You beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix is called an *[agentive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agentive)* suffix, and such words are also often called *agentive* as well.