# When is the correct time to use 'granter' or 'grantor'

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, agent-noun-suffix

We have a [site](http://favo.rs) where we have people grant each other favors.  Within the site, we have copy that says when you grant someone a favor, "you are a 'x'".  Should the person who grants a favor to another person be called a 'granter' or a 'grantor'?

It seems from looking at the dictionary that either would fit, but I'm wondering which one is the best to standardize on.

Comment: Related: [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb)

Comment: @Scott: can you elaborate on "your are a '?'"

Comment: @Peter Sorry, by the '?' I meant, that is where the word 'grantor' or 'granter' would be added.  I used a '?' to be the placeholder since my question is which word should I use in place of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is essentially the difference between adding an *-er* to the end of a verb and using the special noun form of a verb (usually formed like *-or*).

*Grant* as a verb means:

> To give over; to make conveyance of; to give the possession or title of; to convey; -- usually in answer to petition.

So *granter* would be someone who gives over.

*Grantor* has the specific meaning of:

> A person who grants something

In this case, the two definitions seem to be nearly identical. Since the special noun form has a more specific and narrower meaning, I would say you should prefer it over the less specific and broader verbal form, as long as the meaning  of the special noun form fits appropriately.

Comment: I think the semantic distinction is spurious, regardless of how close or different the two supposed meanings are. They're just alternative spellings. The more common form is *grantor*, I suspect simply because it's a semi-legal term, and they are often latinate. Verbs with Latin roots often get an **-or** suffix when converted to nouns, rather than the normal **-er**.

Comment: If you're defining "grantor" using the word "grant", after defining "granter" as someone who does the things that the word "grant" describes... I think you just called them synonyms :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll use "grantor" when you're using very specific legal or financial meanings of the word. (Google it and you'll see a lot of results about selling call or put options, or referring to the person from whom a grant or trust is set up.)

On the other hand, "granter" is a general term you can use to mean "one who grants something."