# Deleter or deletor?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb)

Assuming it would even be a word, how would I describe someone or something that "deletes": `deleter` or `deletor`?

Comment: RegDwight, closer, shouldn't you link to the exact duplicate?

Comment: The link is just above your question.

Comment: [Deleter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deleter)

Answer (score 2):

I have not found either word in a dictionary, nor am I familiar with them in everyday English.

You could use [*eraser*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eraser).

> a person or thing that erases.

Where [*erase*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/erase) means, among other things:

> To remove (data) from computer storage.

But as FumbleFingers says, it makes more sense to name it after the whole function of the object. E.g. *File eraser*.

Comment: I don't think I'd even recommend OP to use *eraser*. It's so commonly used to mean either the plastic/rubber thingy you use to erase pencil marks on paper, or the cloth/felt pad for erasing chalk marks on a blackboard, that any other usage would probably look odd. I'd stick to using the appropriate descriptive phrase for the exact context. It's the **erase head** on magnetic tape recorders, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers agreed, updated

Comment: Actually, 'eraser' is particularly a US English and possibly Canadian English term, for what's called a 'rubber' in most other forms of English.

Comment: Sure, but *rub out* is not an idiomatic way to say you are deleting something. I only works in contexts with a physical action, like on a white board, or a piece of paper.

Comment: In US English, a "rubber" is a condom, so be careful!