# Forming occupational nouns: Why do you say "butcher" and not "butchian" or "butchor"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, morphology, agent-nouns

**Question:** Occupational nouns (butcher, sailor, musician, etc.) have various suffixes in English (er, or, ee, ant, etc.). Is there a set of rules to form occupational nouns from the verbs or their object (butchering, sailing, etc.)?

**Explanation:** 
For example, what are the rules to go from this to this:
Leadership / Leading ---->  Leader
...And not 'Leadian'

In the same way, when we 'invent' occupational nouns, how do we know that some are more correct than others? For instance, how do we know that 'low-self-esteemer' sounds more correct than 'low-self-esteemian'?

I have considered finding a regular expression part of speech tagger to give me a list of noun constructions. However, these do not have a separate category for 'occupation nouns'. More importantly still, they would not explain the rules for forming occupational nouns from verbs/objects, but only for identifying them.

So where are the rules for forming occupational nouns from verbs or objects?

Comment: *-er* vs. *-or* [have been covered before](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4733/). Several times over, in fact, as you can see by browsing the [agent-noun-suffix](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agent-noun-suffix) tag. [*-ian*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ian) is a separate story, but as you can see from the dictionary entry, it's not an agent noun suffix to begin with. A musician is not someone who musics, a lesbian is not someone who lesbs, and a Colombian is not someone who colombs. Likewise, a leadian would be someone related to lead; not someone who leads.

Comment: And a [farrier](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=farrier) is not someone who "farries", nor is a [haberdasher](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=haberdasher) someone who "haberdashes".

Comment: And a finger is not someone who fings. Nor is a costermonger someone who costermongs (or costmongs). And an accordion is not something that accords.

Comment: So, "Is there a set of rules?" Whether the answer is a 'No' or 'Nobody knows,' it still counts and will be useful for reference, so long as it is a reliable statement.

Comment: @Robusto: I know you are cracking jokes, but as a courtesy to future readers who might not realize that: yours is precisely my point. The *-er* in *finger* (from P.Gmc. *fingraz*) is not an agent noun suffix, either. Neither is the first *-er* in *costermonger* (see *costard*); the second actually is (*monger*, formerly *manger*, comes from the now-obsolete verb *mangian*, "to traffic, trade").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good counter examples given and
we have narrowed the search to finding a set of rules for deriving ‘agent noun suffixes’ from their verbs and outcomes.

Comment: @user32103: I put up those two examples primarily because they're cases where we do actually apply the most common rule (*-er* suffix denotes *one who does [something]*), even though what comes before it isn't even a verb in the first place. In a sci-fi context, for example, you might well come across ***spacer*** for *one who live/works in space*, because that form is *still productive*. Most if not all other forms are only there through historical accident, so they're not so much "rules" (to make new words) as "explanations" (of existing words).

Comment: @Robusto The chords on the bass side of a modern accordion do accord, hence the name: The oldest name for this group of instruments is actually harmonika, from the Greek harmonikos, meaning harmonic, musical. Today, native versions of the name accordion are more common. These names are a reference to the type of accordion patented by Cyrill Demian, which concerned "automatically coupled chords on the bass side" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke

Answer (score 3):

An occupational noun derived from a *verb* usually [ends in *-er* or *-or*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb) and means "one who does [verb]". E.g.: *jumper, eater, runner, walker, sailor* etc.

An occupational noun that is derived from another *noun* will usually end in *-ian*. For example, *librarian* is derived from the noun *library*; there is no verb *to library*.

You could say that occupational nouns that end in *-ian* mean something like "one who works at/for/with [noun]". For example, a musician is "one who works with music" (not "one who musics" because there is no verb *to music*).

There are exceptions, but I think this is a good rule of thumb.