# What type of word describes someone who performs an action?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

In English most verbs have a form that describes the person that performs the action.  Some examples would be Runner, Climber, or Jumper.  What are these kinds of words called?  Are the called the same thing as words like Guitarist, Pianist, or Scriptorian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Runner, climber, jumper* are [agent nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun), and *-er* is an [agent noun suffix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb) used to create nouns from verbs.

Whether *guitarist* or *pianist* are agent nouns, depends on your definition. At any rate, in these cases the suffix *-ist* creates nouns from other nouns, not from verbs, so morphologically  there is no action it is the agent of. In addition, in the case of *pianist*, the noun wasn't even formed in English, but was [borrowed as a whole from French](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pianist&allowed_in_frame=0). So in English, there is no suffix in it at all. The whole word is the root.

*Scriptorian* is not a noun I have heard before or was able to find [in any dictionary](http://onelook.com/?w=scriptorian&ls=a).

Comment: *Scriptorian* is an adjective, not a noun — at least per the OED. They equate it to *scriptory*, which can be both an adjective and rarely a noun.  As an adjective, *scriptory* means about writing; as a noun, it is the same as the unnaturalized *scriptorium*.  It does not mean a writer.

Comment: scriptorium (n.)
"writing room," 1774, from Late Latin scriptorium "place for writing," noun use of neuter of Latin scriptorius "pertaining to writing," from Latin scriptus, past participle of scribere "to write" (see script (n.)).

Comment: Yes, I know what a scriptorium is. I know what script is. I even understand what *scriptorian* is supposed to mean as an adjective, or as a noun for that matter. What I am saying is that it "is not a noun I have heard before or was able to find in any dictionary".

Answer (score -2):

'Actor' appears to be close to one who does a certain action.
In fact I am searching for an appropriate word that describes this. My dad suggested 'stalwart'.