# Are there rules to determine whether a musician's title will end with “-er” or “-ist”?

Tags: terminology, word-usage

There are drummers, buglers, fifers, whistlers, and fiddlers. Folks who play all the other instruments use the -ist suffix — pianist, violinist, cellist, tympanist, guitarist, flautist, etc., etc., ad nauseam. What determines which suffix should be used?

Comment: **-er** is common in English (because of its Germanic roots).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What’s the rule for adding “-er” vs. “-or” when nouning a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb)

Comment: Surprisingly, all the attempts so far seem to end in informed opinion but no significant answer!

Comment: What about *music **-ian*** itself? There are: *-er, -or, -ar, -ist, -ian, -ant, -an, -ive, -ess, -man, -person ...* to list some suffixes.

Comment: I always thought the more mundane day-to-day people are *-ers,* the rarer, higher-level, specialists (note the *-ist*) are *-ists* or *-ans.* Also, it's quite true what @oerkelens has noted about verbs taking the *-er* suffix, with maybe some exceptions (one who types should be a typer, not a typist?).

Comment: One who drives is a driver; one who pilots is not a *piloter, but one who **runs** and engine is an engineer -- what gives?

Comment: @Kris - the engineer drives the train. The guy who runs the engine is called a fireman. Just language being illogical.

Comment: @MystiSinha no, that question does not mention "-ist"

Comment: As with many other similar questions, the rule is simple: you look it up in the dictionary, and see which form(s) you find there. :)

Comment: "Horner" or "hornist"?—that is the question.

Answer (score 69):

What strikes me is that the *-er* ones look like they are derived from **verbs**: a drummer drums, a fiddler fiddles, a whistler whistles.

A guitarist *plays* guitar, a pianist *plays* piano.

So if the instrument is also (used) as a verb, we seem to prefer deriving the name for the musician from that verb, rather than from the instrument.

Comment: I wanted to say the same. Actually I always took as granted that this is the case.

Comment: …and, of course, a conductor conducts.

Comment: Most would agree -- including the BBC http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv177.shtml -- but it's still an opinion or at best a rule that's only sometimes followed.

Comment: So a bugler bugles, and a fifer fifes?

Comment: @Ypnypn: yes, [fife](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fife) is a verb, albeit archaic.

Comment: Your last sentence is right but backwards. If there is a verbal form, then you can use the -er ending, but the lack of one necessitates the -ist.  Fiddlers can play the fiddle, Pianists can play the piano. But, while fiddlers can fiddle, pianists can pian. :)

Comment: @AffableGeek: I meant my sentence exactly as it stands: _piano_ is not a verb, so we always say pianist. _Drum_ is a verb, so we can choose _drummer_ or _drummist_. And we prefer to use the form from the verb (drummer) rather than the form from the instrument (drummist). So indeed, if the instrument is also a verb we prefer to derive the musician from the verb. (We _prefer_ because after all, we have a choice. It is this preference that causes the question :) )

Comment: @SrJoven~the point of my comment is that if drum(v) came after drum(n), then the suggestion that a drummer is not a drummist because of the existence of drum(v) would fall down, as the verb didn't exist at the time 'drummer' was coined. According to OED, drum(n) came first (1541), then drummer(1573) then drum(v) in 1578. Bugle(n) is dated 1340, bugler from 1840, and bugle(v) from 1862. Not conclusive, I know, but it does suggest that the nouns for both instrument and player came first, followed later by the verb.

Comment: But really all this talk about drummers misses the point, since they are really called percussionists.

Comment: @RoaringFish with respect to the OED--may its definitions exist forever[insert genuflection]--could it really honestly take 32 years for a word to exist for *that guy who plays the drums*?

Comment: @SrJoven ~ Indeed, and the poor guy who blows a bugle didn't get a mention for 500 years, but the important point is that the verbs 'to drum' and 'to bugle' come later than the nouns drummer and bugler, which throws doubt on the the idea that the -er suffix is derived from the verbs. A shame, as it is a neat idea and I may be tempted to use it anyway if pressed. Similar to the port-out-starboard-home and the 75cl testicle... probably not true but very believable.

Comment: @RoaringFish I think I can agree that the practical usage of the performer's appellation precedes the verb. It loops back to the original question, and mine... "What do you call that guy who plays the drums?" At that point, "Why that word?" but then, on some incarnation of SE in the ancient past, "Is there a single word for the action that is performed by beating on a drum?"

Comment: Why was my comment deleted? Is mentioning the lute and lutists against the site's guidelines or something? I meant to back  @oerkelens's answer. A lutist is someone who plays the lute, or a maker of lutes.

Answer (score 16):

Reference *The New Fowler's Modern English Usage.*

**Compare do*er* and perpetrat*or*.** (-or is the Latin agent-noun ending corresponding
to English -er)

> English verbs derived  from Latin —such as act, credit, invent,
>   oppress, possess, prosecute, protect—usually prefer this Latin ending
>   to the **English one in -er.**

Some other verbs, e.g. conquer,
govern, and purvey, not corresponding to
the above description have agent-nouns
in -or owing to their *passage through
French* or through some other circumstance.

A select list of differences may be
of interest: corrupter and corrector, deserter
and abductor; dispenser and distributor,
eraser and ejector.

> Some verbs generate alternative forms, generally preferring
>   **-er for the personal** and **-or for the mechanical agent** (e.g. adapt, convey, distribute,
>   resist)

There are several **-ist** types:

> (a) Forming a simple agent-noun and usually having an accompanying
>   verb in -ize (antagonist, apologist, evangelist, etc.) and an
>   accompanying abstract noun in -ism (antagonism,etc.);
>
> (b) designating a person devoted to some **art**, science, etc., e.g.
>   archaeologist, economist, **artist**↔**instrumentalist**, dramatist, philologist;
>
> (c) designating an adherent of some creed, doctrine, etc., e.g.
>   atheist, Buddhist, Calvinist, hedonist;
>
> (d) modern formations of various kinds, e.g. balloonist, cyclist,
>   fetishist, finalist

Comment: 'Violinist' derives from the instrument being played, not from a verb describing what they do, the art they follow, or a doctrine they adhere to.

Comment: I am absolutely going to tell people I guitarize from now on.

Comment: I would take Fowler's assertion- A guitarist and a pianist -are instrumentalist- and/or artist in their own right.

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to explain the -er musicians' titles as being military-related.  Buglers, fifers, drummers...all are associated with military events, ceremonies, or marching. Even penny-whistlers have accompanied marching men...and anyway, "whistlist" would sound like a roster of card-players.

...But there's an exception. The odd-man-out is the fiddler...not associated with military matters, to the best of my knowledge. Perhaps we can attribute the use of "fiddler" to the informal type of music generally played on a fiddle -- folk and country music -- which condemns the musician to the lowly -er.  If one plays more formal music, one is therefore recognized by all cognoscenti to be a violinist.

But if you'd like a little giggle, try to imagine a contestant at a local banjo and fiddle festival who advertises himself as "Jim-Bob Yokum, Fiddlist".

Comment: There are probably many exceptions: I am a trumpeter, cornetist (not a cornettist - different instrument) and bugler. The first is not military, the second is, and the third definitely is.

Comment: Wouldn't a drummer also be a percussionist?

Comment: @RoaringFish and a fiddler would be a violinist. The divide is so sharply defined that some people believe they are different instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just because they end in [e]? "Trombone" is an exception (There's one in every crowd) and "oboe" and seems problematic - but, when in doubt, you can always say, "He's a ____ (name of instrument) ***player.***

Comment: Drum doesn't end in [e]. I did wonder if it had something to with the phonology, but that idea fell apart when I thought of 'violinist' and 'Berliner'. If we are happy enough to have Berliners in the world, why not violiners? Next thought: etymology.

Answer (score 0):

In the original poster's list of examples, it seems that the words with Germanic origin (such as "drummer") end with "er", and the words with Latin origin (such as "pianist") end with "ist".

Many of music's Latin-origin words are from Italian.