# Is there a rule or pattern for figuring out which suffix should be used when creating a noun from a verb?

Tags: nouns, derivational-morphology

How can we decide which suffix is used to create a noun from a verb?  Consider these suffixes: *-ee, -er, -or, -ment, -al, -ant, -ation*.

For example, when we form the noun "examination" the suffix "-ation" is used, not "-al" or "-ant".

Comment: Derivational morphology is very irregular. Which affix goes with which lexical item is arbitrary, and affixes are mostly not productive any more. The most common kind of morphology is Zero-affix: _shoe_ (n), _shoe_ (v); _walk_ (v), _walk_ (n).

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between *examiner*, *examinee*, *examination*, etc.?  Or are you asking why *-ation* is used on some verbs (such as "examine") instead of *-ment* or *-al*, so that *examinement* or *examinal* could have been the "proper" form instead of *examination*?

Comment: I think this question is Too Broad. There are probably specific questions already asked on ELU for many contexts, such as [*What’s the rule for adding “-er” vs. “-or” when forming an agent noun from a verb?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/), but it's a bit much to expect a single answer to address all of them.

Answer (score 2):

In comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Derivational morphology is very irregular. Which affix goes with which lexical item is arbitrary, and affixes are mostly not productive any more. The most common kind of morphology is Zero-affix: *shoe* (n), *shoe* (v); *walk* (v), *walk* (n).

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: I just clicked through the [*Forming occupational nouns: Why do you say “butcher” and not “butchian” or “butchor”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/) link on the "related" sidebar here. Now I'm left scratching my head wondering whether ***X-ian*** *(musician, logician, mathematician,...)* is still a "productive" suffix in the sense of ***a person** who specialises in things relating to X* (as opposed to simply being a way to create an adjectival form meaning ***relating to X***).