# Which spelling would be more correct: "Evictor" or "Evicter"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, is-it-a-word, dictionaries

Both "[Evictor](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/evictor)" and "[Evicter](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/evicter)" show up at [Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/about). The "Evicter" page is much more substantial, though.

At [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/about/), "[Evictor](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/evictor)" is the only accepted spelling.

[Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=evictor,evicter) shows that "Evictor" is a good deal more popular than "Evicter", but that is most likely due to a particular product which uses the former spelling.

Comment: Latin words take the suffix ***-or***: *Evictor*, for all general English writing. The alternate spelling refers to a legal term  that may sometimes be used in other contexts. Lexico entries cited in the questions too give an idea of this fact. Good Luck.

Comment: I am reminded that IBM once anguished over this topic, when naming some functions of their computers.  As I understood it, they decided that "-er" was to refer to a human actor (don't ask) while "-or" was to refer to a machine-operated thingie.

Comment: @HotLicks Did you perchance meant "... functions of their computORs"? :-P

Comment: @Zano - Never try to tell a computer geek he's being inconsistent!

Comment: @Zano - But actual fact:  "Computer" comes from the people that compute.  Like "Hidden Figures" only earlier, going back to Bletchley Park and before.  The machines are "electronic computers".

Comment: @HotLicks indeed. Before I commented I actually had to stop and reread that it wasn't exactly that distinction IBM had anguished over. Because that would have made sense as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What’s the rule for adding “-er” vs. “-or” when forming an agent noun from a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-forming-an-agent-noun-from-a-ver)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using dictionaries that are responding more rapidly to changes in English use online than the standard dictionaries.  I did not recognise the word(s) you are asking about, and it turns out that neither the Merriam Webster (US) English dictionary, nor the Cambridge nor the Collins (British) English dictionaries recognise the word.

There is no reason why the word should not exist, regardless of the spelling, with the obvious meaning of 'one who evicts'.  [EDIT.  In fact it has existed.  The full Oxford English Dictionary (1992) cites it in reference to both conquerors driving out or bailiffss driving out tenants and spelled *victor* with *victer* as an alternative. But its most recent use is cited for 1888, after which it may have fallen out of use.]

It is derived from the Latin verb *vinco* = *I win/conquer*, from which can be derived the noun *victor* from its supine, *victum*.  The ending of the English noun would, therefore, and of most nouns so derived, end in '-or' rather than '-er', which is the ending for English words with Teutonic endings, such as *Father*, *maker*, *banker*, *runner*.

However, in English, rules are there to be broken.  I know of one exception, which is the use of the *-er* ending for the word *advis**er*** for UK local education authority officers, employed to guide teachers and leaders in schools.  This spelling in *-er* is noted in Merriam, with the *-er* ending as an acceptable alternative.

So by all means coin this word with either spelling.  Who knows?  It might finally reach the major dictionaries.

Comment: +1, but 'Teutonic'?

Comment: Dictionaries, these days, record the language as it is used rather than as someone thinks it ought to be used. There are some people who say 'I don't care that some ignoramus whose work has been read by the people who wrote this dictionary spelled it evicter'; that spelling is just wrong.' Time will tell.

Comment: @JeremyC Yes indeed.  I have no problem with that with one issue.  It makes teaching both of child native speakers and of learners of English problematic.  How you do that without ‘rules of some kind is problematic.

Comment: @AllInOne Well, various germanic languages.

Comment: @Tuffy I doubt that English spelling could ever be reduced to rules. Would it be so terribly wrong to teach them that in this class we spell the word 'evictor', but some people don't?

Comment: @JeremyC Nothing at all, in theory, to a class of bright and confident kids, and maybe to ditto adult learners.  Indeed, one of the drawbacks of phonics as a method of teaching reading is the phonic inconstancy of English spelling.  But for the less able or confident or for speakers of other languages, used to more consistently applied rules, it would be much harder.

Comment: This issue (-er vs. -or) has a pretty good discussion [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-forming-an-agent-noun-from-a-ver)

Answer (score 0):

I would used ***evictor***. But I don't think this is a matter of "correctness".

As you note, the two words each have dictionary entries and certainly mean the same thing. One could dive into the etymology of *-er* and *-or* as in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-forming-an-agent-noun-from-a-ver), but you didn't ask about this. I don't think you're looking for a post hoc justification of which is theoretically correct, but rather asking "which word should I use".

An easy answer is to use whichever occurs more commonly. By looking at Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evictor%2Cevicter&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevictor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevicter%3B%2Cc0), we see that *evictor* is in fact significantly more common in modern usage. Note that, unlike Google Trends which reports search volume, Google Ngrams relies on occurrences in books. This often makes it a better tool to study the use of language.

Another thing to note in the Ngrams graph is that *evicter* was much more popular until the 19th century. This trend is also documented in the [OED entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62497659) for the word. Perhaps historical popularity explains why *evicter* is still used from time to time, even when *evictor* is vastly more popular today.

Comment: Thank you for this.  You made me look again at my real (paper) full Oxford English Dictionary for 1992.  I have corrected my answer to reflect that it has existed, but with no cited use after 1888.  So it was probably moribund and has apparently been reborn.