# Why don't the names of the devices, in which evaporation and condensation occur, have the same ending in English?

Tags: germanic-languages

In thermodynamics, the *evaporator* evaporates and the *condenser* condenses a substance. While these devices have the same ending in other languages (e.g. French and German), how did it come to pass that these aren't called *evaporator and condensator* or *evaporenser and condenser* in English? Is this just a curious artifact of random change over time?

Comment: A quick look at the etymologies should tell you what these words / their precursors  looked like when they were assimilated into English.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @Edwin Ashworth. Both precursors come from latin (_condenso_ and _evaporo_) but only one follows the rule posted in the linked answer (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-forming-an-agent-noun-from-a-ver). As such, the question has not yet been answered and should be reopened.

Comment: I didn't CV for the reason most did, but for lack of easily found research _presented with the question with attributed link/s_.

Comment: Apparently, the base words evaporate and condense arrived in English in the same forms they have now. Far more -ator agent nouns ([The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ator) lists 873 words ending in -ator with few false positives) are found than -ater agent nouns (correspondingly 297, with many false positives like breakwater). The ratio is reversed with -sor and -ser.