# Is it franchiser, or franchisor?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes, agent-noun-suffix

From this morning, in an online conversation, of mine, about Econo Lodge franchises.

My usual on-line go-to place to resolve such close differences in words is, https://wikidiff.com/franchiser/franchisor .

I see that franchiser is a synonym of franchisor, whereas, franchiser is more basic in the sense of further latitude in meaning.  Which option makes more sense, in the above noted sense?

franchiser

English
Noun
(en noun)
A franchisor, a company which or person who grants franchises.
(rare) A person who has the right to vote.

- 1843 ,", book 3, chapter XIII, "Democracy
  No man oppresses thee, O free and independent Franchiser : but does not this stupid Porter-pot oppress thee? No Son of Adam can bid thee come or go; but this absurd Pot of Heavy-wet, this can and does!

franchisor

English
Noun
(en noun)
A company which or person who grants franchises.
Synonyms

- franchiser

Comment: See also: [What’s the rule for adding “-er” vs. “-or” when forming an agent noun from a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/what-s-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-forming-an-agent-noun-from-a-ver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusion seems to have arisen between **franchiser** and **franchisee**. The "-ee" suffix refers to the one who may accept something and the "er" usually refers to the one furnishing that thing thing (Compare **offerer** - 2. A person who presents something for acceptance; one who makes an offer or proposal; and offeree - a person to whom something is or has been offered;)

However, confusion was introduced between the -er suffix and the -or suffix. They are normally considered to be the same and implying the agent doing the action (inspector; worker).

As if this were not enough, the law then had  mortgagor - the borrower in a mortgage, typically a homeowner., and mortgagee  the lender in a mortgage, typically a bank. **BUT** a ***mortag*er** -> a person who mortgages property (and hence) the borrower in a mortgage; = mortgagor n. *Also occasionally (in popular use): the creditor or lender in a mortgage; = mortgagee n. 2*

And so it is with Franchiser and franchiser and franchisee. The distinctions between agent and patient have become confused.

The OED gives

> **franchiser, n.**
>
> **Etymology:** Partly < franchise n. + -er suffix1, and partly < franchise v. + -er suffix1.
> **A person in possession of a franchise, [...] or who grants a franchise, esp. (originally U.S.) a commercial one (see franchise n.2e, and cf. franchisor n.).**
>
> 1976   Times 14 Dec. 20/2   *Kentucky Fried Chicken, second to Wimpy..as Britain's largest food franchisers, is planning a £1.25m expansion programme.*
>
> **franchisor, n.**
>
> **Etymology:** < franchise v. + -or suffix. ***Compare earlier franchiser n. and franchisee n.***
>
> **A person who or company which grants commercial franchises (franchise n. 2e). Cf. franchiser n.**
>
> 1990   Reader's Digest Aug. 130/1   *Because advertising, training, supply and other services are provided by the franchisor, a franchise has a much better chance of succeeding than an independent company.*
>
> **franchisee, n.**
>
> **Etymology:** < franchise v. + -ee suffix1. ***Compare earlier franchiser n.***   A holder of a commercial franchise (franchise n.2e).
>
> 1966   Economist 9 July 148/1   *Franchisers, to be successful, must to some degree tell their franchisees what to sell and at what price.*

Thus franchiser and franchisee may be the same, as may franchisor and franchiser.

All definitions = OED

*Edit to add earliest record of the words:*

**Franchiser** originally meant a person with a vote:

> 1555   R. Sherry Treat. Figures Gram. & Rhetorike f. lxiiv   *For the Citizens of Rome, both wer thei fraunchisers, and brought out of other countreys, there to enhabite.*

But was repurposed in American English to someone who holds a franchise.

> 1889   Oakland (Calif.) Tribune 2 Dec. 1/2   *The apparatus is intended to assist railroad franchisers to turn the corners of streets with their cable cars.*

> 1949   Wall St. Jrnl. 1 Feb. 6/5   *Hertz supplies accounting information, helps franchisers set up rate structures and advises them on buying equipment.*

> **Franchisee:** 1956   Trademark Reporter 46 45   *Opposer adopted the word slim for vitamin-fortified skim milk in 1949 and by use of franchises extended the sale of its products to 40 dairies in 21 states. Mark is normally used in conjunction with the primary mark of the franchisee.*

> **Franchisor** 1960   Jrnl. Marketing 25 102/1   *The franchisor's activities are largely contained in the establishment of ‘brand recognition’ and in advertising in the areas where franchised outlets operate to establish recognition.*

Comment: So, is the gist of the answer that that *franchis**er*** is ambiguous in that it can stand for either side of the relationship, but *francis**or*** is not?

Comment: Yes, from what I see, that is so.

Answer (score 2):

The [definition of a franchiser](https://www.yourdictionary.com/franchiser) is a company that {offers} franchise rights to those who want to own a franchise.

The [definition of a franchisor](https://www.yourdictionary.com/franchisor#wiktionary) is a company which or person who has granted {and governs} a franchise.

So if you are referring to someone (or some company) that offers franchise rights, use franchiser, but if you are referring to the entity that granted franchise rights, use franchisor.

"The ABC company is a franchiser who became the franchisor of John's new company."

For additional sourcing, read [Franchisor](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/franchisor.html) and [Franchiser](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/franchiser.html).

Comment: The facts that the Online Business Dictionary only list one variant and Wikidiff labels these as synonyms surely strongly suggest they're best seen as spelling variants.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I've worked in the business world for over 30 years and can tell you the above distinction is valid.  I added two more sources to help you recognize that some dictionaries do not make the distinction, but others (and active professionals) do.

Comment: I upvoted but then I changed my mind because I don't fully understand the ***difference*** between (i) *a company  that allows its products or services to be franchised* and (ii) *The company that allows an individual (known as the ‘franchisee’) to run a location of their business.* I also find it odd that the term *franchiser* is never mentioned in the [Wikipedia article “franchising”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchising) while “franchisor” appears 94 times. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: One has to assume the dictionaries correctly sample usages, and therefore that the words are used synonymously at times. This means that 'specifying definitions' must be being used in those parts of the business world you mention (I'm sure there are variations just as in almost all domains other than Linnaean classification). This always leads to confusion (the meteoreologist's hurricane not necessarily being the layman's).

Comment: Good question @jsw29.  Providing is actively franchising (the franchise has already been granted and it's active), while granting initiates franchising (it has not been granted but could be).  For example, you have already posted your question, but prior to making your post, you could have--'could have' is a franchiser, while 'you already' is a franshisor.

Comment: @jsw29 - yes, B has the right, but A must govern the right.  B can't do anything they want, and A must monitor and enforce that right, and that is what a franchisor does.  A franchiser offer rights to people/organizations that might be interested/able, while a franchisor monitors and enforces (and profits from) rights given.

Comment: @Christopher Do you mean that a company which offers franchises but has not had any taken up is is a _franchiser_ but as soon as one franchise has been taken up it becomes the _franchisor_ for that franchise? Does that also mean that the same company is simultaneously a _franchiser_ in that it is offering additional franchises and a franchisor in that it is managing and profiting from the granted franchise(s)? That seems like a very subtle difference to me.

Comment: @ BoldBen - simply put, an offerer=er, a providor=or.  A company that offers franchising rights is a franchiser because they are offering them.  But once someone agrees to be a franchisee, the franchiser becomes a franchisor to the franchisee only.  A franchiser offers, and franchisor governs the agreement and financially benefits.  An example would be the difference between a salesman and a contractor--the salesman is a salesman before the sale, and becomes a contractor after the sale. (see additional explanation below)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A please see my reply to BoldBen above

Comment: @jsw29 please see my reply to BoldBen above

Comment: @ BoldBen - continued from above - We don't use the word, Contracter, because we don't differentiate between the offerer and the provider, but Franchiser/Franchisor does.

Comment: You fail to include 'franchiser
a company or manufacturer that grants franchises
also sp. fran′chi·sor' in your first definition, which is misquoting. And I fail to see where your _specifying definitions_ are supported in your other quotes. If you actually use such specialist usages, you need (on ELU) to give a reference actually contrasting (in one article) those specified definitions. They certainly aren't the only ones.