# Which is the proper spelling: "Adapter" or "adaptor"?

Tags: differences, orthography, suffixes, agent-noun-suffix

In my current project we are writing a program to convert a newer protocol to an older one.

These conversion programs are being referred to as *adapters*, but the team cannot agree which spelling to use: *adapter* or *adaptor*.

I personally plump for *adapter*, as *adaptor* sounds like its a person (like *actor*, *realtor*, etc.) rather than a device.

Is there a case for using one rather than the other?

Comment: Related questions: ["What's the rule for adding -er vs. -or when nouning a verb?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/whats-the-rule-for-adding-er-vs-or-when-nouning-a-verb) (great first answer), ["What's the difference between 'adviser' and 'advisor' and are both interchangeable?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/what-is-the-difference-between-adviser-and-advisor-and-are-both-interchangeable), and ["Commenter vs. Commentator"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/commentor-vs-commentator)

Comment: So as "adapt" comes from latin (albeit second hand via French) then the "or" suffix should be more correct.

Comment: “In my current project we are writing a program to convert a newer protocol to an older one...  the team cannot agree which spelling to use: adapter or adaptor.” — it’s always issues like this that are hardest to settle on, isn’t it?

Comment: According to this link http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-or#Suffix the "or" suffix does strictly refer to a person so my original instinct to go for the "er" suffix for a program/device was probably correct!

Comment: @James Anderson: There's probably a strong tendency to use "-or" just for people, but it's not a hard-and-fast rule - otherwise object-oriented programming languages would have "constructers" and "destructers" instead of constructors and destructors :)

Comment: @psmears -- but we coders think of our creations as people, or at least pets :-)

Comment: so, do you think of tractors as being persons? ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both are commonly used and listed in dictionaries, but adapter (with an e) is usually listed as the more common - see, for example, [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptor?show=0&t=1303719620) or the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/adapter_1). It's not a strong basis for choosing one over the other, but it might be enough to settle the matter in your case :).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I think Billares links sent me off in the right direction!

Comment: Really? I have never, ever seen "adapter".

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, really :) If you don't trust the dictionary sources I mentioned (one UK, one US), try picking a website (e.g. [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/) or [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/) news, or your local Amazon site) and searching for both spellings... in all the searches I've tried, [adapter dominates](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=adaptor&word2=adapter).

Comment: Clearly, it is not uncommon, but it's still a new one on me.

Comment: Interesting. ASL has an sign for an agent (e.g. learner/student, teacher) which also applies to inanimate objects like printers (PRINT+AGENT).

Answer (score 12):

I would tend to suggest in a situation like this where both spellings are considered acceptable to use the spelling that is most broadly accepted in the particular field you are working in.  In this case, the leading example of usage of the word "adapter" is the description of the kind of system you are writing in *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* by Gamma, Helms, Johnson and Vlissides, commonly referred to as "Gang of Four" or "GoF".  This book (which is among the most widely-read books on software design there are) uses the -er spelling, so I would suggest that anybody else working on software adapters should also use that spelling.

Answer (score 6):

The British newspaper The Guardian, for instance, makes a distinction between adaptor vs. adapter in its internal style guide, namely, use adaptor when referring to devices and adapter when referring to people.

Comment: Interesting... The original post suggested the exact opposite - "or" for people and "er" for devices, which is also backed up by [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-or#Suffix). Do you have a link to the Guardian style guide?

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](http://grammarist.com/spelling/adapter-adaptor/) a good article on the subject... essentially, there is no 'correct' answer to this question.

Incidentally, some would argue quite the opposite in regards to either form referring to people or objects. There are (not literally of course) endless examples of people roles ending in -er. Caterer, lecturer, carpenter etc.

Answer (score 1):

The "or" suffix tends to be more common in American English.  In English English, the "er" prefix is usually preferred when not referring to a person.  In this instance I would certainly use ***Adapter***.

Comment: Sorry, that's factually incorrect. The "er" suffix is more common in both regions. See ngram for [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adapter%2Cadaptor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) and [American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adapter%2Cadaptor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) referenced in [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/adapter-adaptor/) and [WritingExplained](http://writingexplained.org/adapter-vs-adaptor-difference).